# Form Validation Laravel Session Data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am trying to do `form validation` with `sentry` using `laravel4`. When I use the code shown below the errors are catched but the `Session` data does not seem to be sent back to the `View` to inform the user of the problem when logging in. Is there something I am doing wrong? I've been passing `Session` data between my views like this all through my application.

This is my `Controller Action`:

```
public function handleLogin() { 
    try{
        $credentials = array(
            'email'    => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
        );

        $user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
        if($user){
            if($user->hasAccess('admin')){//Admin Base Controller - Dashboard Display welcome
                return Redirect::action('BookController@index')->with('message', $user->first_name . " " . $user->last_name);
            }else{//User Base Controller - Dashboard Display 
                return Redirect::to('user/dashboard/')->with('message', 'Welcome User');
            }
        }   
    //Error with logging in redirect to login page and display error
    }catch(Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException $e){
        return View::make('home.login')->with('message', 'Login field is required.');
    }catch(Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\PasswordRequiredException $e){
        return View::make('home.login')->with('message', 'Password field is required. ');
    }catch(Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\WrongPasswordException $e){
        return View::make('home.login')->with('message', 'Wrong password, try again.');
    }catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e){
        return View::make('home.login')->with('message', 'User was not found.');
    }catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotActivatedException $e){
        return View::make('home.login')->with('message', 'User is not activated.');
    }
}
```

This is my `View`:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dissmissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <strong>Goodbye: </strong>{{ Session::get('message') }}
    </div>
@endif

@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dissmissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <strong>Success: </strong>{{ Session::get('success') }}
    </div>
@endif


    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>  
    <!-- Login Form -->
    <form action="{{action('HomeController@handleLogin')}}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"/>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </form>
@stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `View::make()->with('foo', 'Error')` passes `$foo` as variable instead of setting the Session variable.

Perhaps you can try:

```
@if(isset($message))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dissmissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <strong>Goodbye: </strong>{{ $message }}
    </div>
@endif
```